# How can I use matrix operation to represent the following result?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, python, matlab, linear-algebra

I need to derive a pairwise offset matrix from the two known data array $X_{n \times p}$ and $Y_{m \times p}$, in which the offset are derived from values at corresponding locations $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$ in the two array. The following figure shows an example:

[image]

How can I derive the offset matrix $D_i$ using matrix operations (vectorized code)? I wll also appreciate that you can give me an example using a code platform, such as Python, R or Matlab. Thank you.

Comment: use the built-in function dist on the two columns separately: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/dist

Comment: in MATLAB: `D_i = X(:,i) - Y(:,i)'`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the columns of $D_1$ in a list by doing

```
cols <- lapply(1:m, function(i) X[1, ] - Y[i, 1])
```

Then you bind them by doing `do.call(cbind, cols)`.

Similar for $D_2$.